# Casting an object to the same type but different package

Tags: java, mapstruct

I have an object, let's call it X who type is:

```
en.testmodule.utils.gestionmoduleone.model.PagedDataAndSortDto
```

I want to cast it to:

```
en.utilities.dto.PagedDataAndSortDto (This dto is in another project)
```

In reality, they are the same, but with each project, I generate a PagedDataAndSortDto which changes the package, example:

Project 1:

```
en.testmodule.utils.gestionmoduleone.model.PagedDataAndSortDto
```

Project 2:

```
en.testmoduletwo.utils.gestionmoduleone.model.PagedDataAndSortDto
```

Is there any way I can cast the first type to the standard in the another project?

I have tried using Mapstruct, but you can't use generic values there.

This is what I have tried:

```
   @Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public abstract class PagedDataAndSortDtoMapper<T, S> {
    @Mapping(target = "NP", source = "NP")
    @Mapping(target = "PP", source = "PP")
    @Mapping(target = "PN", source = "PN")
    public abstract T fromHuerfana(S input);

}
```

And this is the error I've got:

> Can't generate mapping method for a generic type variable source

Comment: Does one of them extend the other? If they don't then you definitely can't cast one to the other. Casting in Java doesn't change objects: it only changes the type that a reference is assumed to be (and checks that the assumptions is correctly, usually). In short: they are probably not *the same* in any sense that Java knows or cares about.

Comment: No, they don't extend... Is there any way to obtain this?

Comment: Something like mapstruct will likely be necessary, so I suggest you [edit] your question to describe what you tried there and how/why it failed.

Comment: Edited, added the class I've tried

Comment: Classes in different packages are … distinct classes. Unless one extends the other, you cannot cast them.

Comment: You can use jackson to convert it to json then convert that json into the object from another package.

Comment: If it's in a different package, then **it is a different type**, and it **does not matter** if the name is the same. If the types are not related by inheritance, then casting will not be possible.

Comment: "In reality, they are the same, but with each project, I generate a PagedDataAndSortDto wich changes the package" - **Don't do that. That is the cause of the problem.** Instead, just import and use the same single definition in the places that need it. That's supposed to be part of the point of writing classes, right? Code reuse?

Comment: Why not create a simple library for all your common classes and use them in all your projects? Or do you have a "master project" that you use in every other one - put it there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the object to json string first then convert back to object using `ObjectMapper`. If you have a object named 'a.Pojo' and want to convert to `b.Ano`, you can do the following

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
Ano ano = objectMapper.readValue(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(pojo), Ano.class);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, for now this solutions works flawlessly. But I am going to investigate further if I can find another solution. Thank you all for the answers

Answer (score 2):

IMO, using Jackson's `ObjectMapper` is shoving the problem under the rug.

You have two separate classes that just *happen* to look the same. If one of these changes, due to:

- Developer error
- A bug in your code generation code
- Any other reason

then the `ObjectMapper` approach might end up causing a lot of frustration due to some hard-to-find bugs ("why is this field null? I set it!").

Ideally, you would have a "leading" service which provides the models for its domain and exports these as a standalone library so that any other service that uses them is in agreement about what the objects look like.

If the refactoring hurdle is too great for the above approach, I would still recommend MapStruct for this use case instead of `ObjectMapper` so as to avoid unnecessary overhead from the reflection shenanigans that `ObjectMapper` performs and have a bit more type/field-safety when mapping between objects.